# Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Tags: magento2, controllers, forms

Controller file code below, data get print successfully but throw Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

```
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

                if ($data) {
                    if(!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
                        $websiteId  = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
                            $name = $data['customer_name'];
                            $email = $data['customer_email'];
                            $password = $data['password'];

                        //print_r ($name); die('');
                        //Here data get print

                            // $name = 'af';
                            // $email = 'abc@gmail.com';
                            // $password = '123123123';

                            //Using custom values it works fine

                            // Instantiate object
                            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
                            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        
                            // Preparing data for new customer
                            $customer->setEmail("$email"); 
                            $customer->setFirstname("$name");
                            $customer->setLastname(" ");
                            $customer->setPassword("$password");
        
                            // Save data
                            $customer->save();
                            //$customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
                        }
                    
                    $model = $this->investmentFactory->create();
                    $model->setData($data)->save();
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__("Data Saved Successfully."));
            }
            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e, __("We can\'t submit your request, Please try again."));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every works fine, the error was that Email id already exists, So I just get implement if condition and check that if email id already exists then display an error message "Email id already exist, try another one"

```
public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

                if ($data) {    
                    if(!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
                        $websiteId  = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();

                            $name = $data['customer_name'];
                            $email = $data['customer_email'];
                            $password = $data['password'];

                            $customerData = $this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('email', $email);
                            
                            // Instantiate object
                            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
                            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                        
                        if(!count($customerData)) {
                            // Preparing data for new customer
                            $customer->setEmail($email); 
                            $customer->setFirstname($name);
                            $customer->setLastname(" ");
                            $customer->setPassword($password);
        
                            // Save data
                            $customer->save();
                            //$customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
                            $model = $this->investmentFactory->create();
                            $customerData1 = $this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('email', $email);
                            foreach($customerData1 as $customer){
                                $id =  $customer->getId();
                            }
                            $data['customer_id'] = $id;
                        
                        }else{
                            $this->messageManager->addError(__("Email id already exist, try another one"));
                            $resultRedirect = $this->resultPageFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
                            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
                            return $resultRedirect;
                        }           
                    }
                    $model = $this->investmentFactory->create();
                    $model->setData($data)->save();
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__("Data Saved Successfully."));
                }
            }
            
         catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e, __("We can\'t submit your request, Please try again."));
        }
```